# Sharepoint 2013 display templates look different to users

Tags: 2013, branding, display-template

As admin user everything looks fine on the site, but when I log on as a normal user the display templates gets another look. Some of the display templates also get an error "Sorry, something went wrong".

First as normal user I didn't get any pictures, but when I disabled the limited access user permission lockdown mode - feature, I got the picture back. Now I have two strange behavior on the same page. One of the DT (custom) looks different to normal and admin users, looks like some css / js missing.

Then there is the display template that only show "Sorry, something went wrong".

Comment: Have to checked 15 hive to check actual logs?It seems like permission issue.

Comment: I've "re-installed" the display templates, and then they suddenly start behaving like normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a permissions issue, admin have full access and hence why disabling limited access user permission lockdown mode it works for the images.

**css/JS issue**

You need to see within your masterpage/DT where the css are being referenced from? are they on 15hive? if they are than the files/folder needs have the correct security settings applied for wss_wpg and wss_admin_wpg:

right click file (css)-> properties -> securities tab -> check those two groups are in the list. if not add them with read / excecute access and read access. For admin group its full access!

if its same or many items within the folder than you could click on the parent folder, right click, -> properties -> security tab -> advanced button -> change permissions button -> tick 'Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object' -> click ok and do iisreset

as for:

**display template that only show "Sorry, something went wrong**

make sure that your DT is published properly. Look in sharepoint for all masterpages and display templates librarys to make sure that all are published as major versions and not minor (draft) or not published at all.

Comment: My fix was to update my solution and re-enable the feature. In other words, delete display templates and then replace them again, remember to publish! Ty @ali for great respons

Comment: @Plexus81 no problem! funny enough at work i have people with the same issue as they keep on forgetting to publish content and complaining why they see differnet to others lol :)